# Mobile Framework - insert action results in a 404

Tags: acumatica

I have created a new screen in Acumatica that I am now attempting to expose to the Mobile Framework.

The screen is a simplified order entry screen based on the customers needs that is a FormDetail view (one form, one grid).   From in Acumatica the screen is working correctly.

The screen has been named as "CW301000"

Now that I'm attempting to expose this to the framework, I can get existing items to show and add detail line items to existing items however when attempting to add a new base item, the framework is throwing a 404 error.

Looking at the information in the help guide everything appears to be correct.

Below is the definition in the framework xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sm:SiteMap xmlns:sm="http://acumatica.com/mobilesitemap" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<sm:Screen DisplayName="Mobile Sales Orders" Icon="system://Cash" Id="CW301000" Type="SimpleScreen" IsDefaultFavorite="true">
     <sm:Container Name="OrderSummary" FieldsToShow="4" >
        <sm:Field Name="MobileOrderNbr" />
        <sm:Field Name="Customer"  />
        <sm:Field Name="Location" />
        <sm:Field Name="OrderDate" />
        <sm:Action Behavior="Create" Context="Container" DisplayName="Add" Name="Insert" Icon="system://Plus" />
        <sm:Action Behavior="Delete" Context="Selection" Icon="system://Trash" Name="Delete" DisplayName="Delete" SyncLongOperation="true"/>
         <sm:Action Behavior="Save" Context="Record" Name="Save"/>
        <sm:Action Behavior="Cancel" Context="Record" Name="Cancel"/>
   </sm:Container>
 </sm:Screen>
</sm:SiteMap>
```

When monitoring the post requests to the server, I see that the following is being posted:

```
/rest/screen/CW301000/OrderSummary/action/Insert?context=Container
```

The server is returning a 404 Not Found.

The insert method is available both from the screen as well as the WDSL definition:

```
<s:complexType name="Actions">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Save" type="tns:Action"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Cancel" type="tns:Action"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Insert" type="tns:Action"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Delete" type="tns:Action"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CopyDocumentCopyPaste" type="tns:Action"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PasteDocumentCopyPaste" type="tns:Action"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SaveTemplateCopyPaste" type="tns:Action"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="First" type="tns:Action"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Previous" type="tns:Action"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Next" type="tns:Action"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Last" type="tns:Action"/></s:sequence></s:complexType>
```

Is this an issue with the framework or is there a key item I'm missing?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging this for a few days I was able to track down the core issue.

The Mobile framework requires that a Note field exist in the DAC for the primary view.

In my case, the noteID field existed but was not properly flagged as a [PXNote].  Once I did that and updated my existing records, the mobile app allowed me to create my records.